# Show all reminders in Google Calendar, without grouping

Tags: google-calendar-reminders

When I have multiple reminders in one day in Google Calendar, they are grouped in a very unhelpful way:

[image]

Is there a way to ungroup the reminders list so that I can see all the reminders concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You have to set times instead of "all day" to see the individual reminders.

Comment: It is very sad.

Comment: Incorrect, even with a time set a reminder event gets grouped with the others regardless.

Comment: [Paul Dion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/208510/paul-dion) wanted to say (can't yet comment) that "even with a time set a reminder event gets grouped with the others".

Answer (score 0):

It is true that multiple reminders set for the same time will be grouped, but it is possible to set multiple reminders for different times, in which case they will appear individually.  The time difference can, of course, but very small, eg 5 minutes